# HDDScan: All bad blocks gone after format

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

A few days ago I scanned my HDD using HDDScan. After 100 000+ consecutive bad blocks I stopped the scan because it was taking hours. Today I formatted the HDD and after scanning it again (verify) the results looked [really healthy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idr1m.png).

Some info:
Before the format the drive was split up into the following partitions:

- 391GB EXT4
- 8.4GB Linux Swap
- 473MB FAT32
- 100GB NTFS
- 431GB NTFS

The bad blocks appeared after about 17% of the drive, or ~70GB of a total 931GB. It's now formatted to a single NTFS partition.

My questions is: Are the bad sectors a problem even though they don't show up anymore and should I replace the drive anyway? Or is it a possibility that the the bad sectors were a false positive caused by the non-NTFS partitions?

Edit:
I ran chkdsk as per Renameduser32s request, these are [the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAppH.png).

Comment: At issue is how to define "bad block".  You only provide vague summations, and no details.  Your *"really healthy"* results seem to be just a quick "speed" test, rather than a comprehensive scan such as a SMART long test.  What kind of format (quick or full)?  A full format would rewrite most sectors, and that could (temporarily) cure issues with head misalignment and/or media wear (that previously caused read errors).

Comment: The test wasn't quick, It was a full verify test (took about 3 hours). The format was a full format (also took about 3 hours).

Comment: *"The format was a full format"* -- Then that can explain some of what you report. You neglect to mention how this drive has been handled.  Some (recent?) event (e.g. shock or overheating or component aging) has slightly affected the drive's ability to read "old" sectors.  But sectors written after this event can be read without issue (at least in the short term).

Comment: You neglect to mention why  you initiated the test in the first place, and if any errors/problems were occurring prior to the test.  If there really were *"100 000+ consecutive bad blocks"* on that drive, wouldn't you expect to have operational issues?

Answer (score 1):

If the disk is new and if it is high quality, then it may have had issues in the first format and setup coming from the way it was used.

In this case, formatting properly and seeing there are no errors, the disk should be perfectly fine to use.

If the disk is older and so has had long use, I would not trust a single format.  Errors could be hidden by this, especially if you used a quick format. Even if CHKDSK reports good, age is against the drive.

This being the case I would replace the drive with a new drive or SSD.

Comment: The disk is about 6 years old and it has been used a lot, so it's definitely not new

Comment: That is a new update. I would replace the drive and amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: @sFyX67v7Ia1XDGFU  "The disk is about 6 years old and it has been used a lot " - get the data off and dump it. It has already warned you once.

Answer (score -1):

The bad blocks are marked in table, that table can be cleared. so a good idea is to perform `chkdsk * /r` then badblocks might re-appear. If your toshiba drive is silent and has no more than 1000 working hours by smartinfo then it should be usable for long time.

Comment: I'm currently running chkdsk and will update my post when I get the results. The drive is silent but probably has way more than 1000 working hours because I have used it a lot for 6 years.

Comment: I ran chkdsk, the results are in an edit in the original question